# Couldn't find a suitable constructor for class TunnelData to initialize with {}, null, null, null

Tags: flutter, vpn, wireguard

i just try project https://github.com/tark/wireguard-flutter-poc
when running debug its good but if running release showing error Couldn't find a suitable constructor for class TunnelData to initialize with {}, null, null, null

this code

```
class TunnelData(
  val name: String,
  val address: String,
  val listenPort: String,
  val dnsServer: String,
  val privateKey: String,
  val peerAllowedIp: String,
  val peerPublicKey: String,
  val peerEndpoint: String,
  val preSharedKey: String
)
```

Comment: Does it `dart` related class?

Comment: No, that MainActivity.kt